# I get an error when trying to run glue job locally in cmd

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, data-science, aws-glue

I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html) to run glue scripts locally. I checked in cmd if spark and maven are installed and it confirmed it by showing the installed version.

Now when I try to run a glue script by typing:

```
./bin/gluesparksubmit "path_to_python_script"
```

I get the error that the dot operator could not be found. How could I solve this? I already googled that and could not find a solution for that

Comment: Just checking that you're not trying to run this within a Windows CMD prompt?

Comment: What should I use to run this?

Comment: On Windows, you can try Powershell.